# Input react wrapper

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-component

I want to make a form for user data and I was asked to make a wrapper react components for each type of input. My problem is passing the handler to the input component.

```
This is my form:

import React from 'react';
import {addUser as addNewUser} from '../../services/index';
import {TextBox} from './TextBox'

interface AddUserProps{

}

interface AddUserState{
    UserName:string,
  
}

export default class AddUser extends React.Component<AddUserProps, AddUserState> {
    constructor(props:any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            UserName: '',
          
        };

        this.updateUserName = this.updateUserName.bind(this);
    }

    updateUserName(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        this.setState({UserName: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();  
        console.log(this.state)  
        addNewUser(this.state)
           
    }

    render() {
   
             
        return (
            <div>
            
            <form
             className = "user-add-form"
             onSubmit={(event) => this.handleSubmit(event)}
            >            
                <h3>Adauga utilizatori:</h3>
                <label htmlFor="userName">User Name:</label>
                <TextBox name="userName" type="text" value={userName} handleChange={this.updateUserName}/>

                
                <input type="submit"  value="Add user"/>
            </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export {AddUser};
```

And this is the input component that I made:

```
import React from 'react'

export function TextBox(props) {
   
    return (
        <div>
            <input type={props.type}
                   name={props.name} 
                   value={props.value} 
                   onChange={(event) => props.HandleInput(event)}                 
             />
        </div>
    )
}
```

So what I don't know is how to pass the event handler to the input component, because as it is right now it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

It should exist in Textbox's props as `handleChange` as it's passed in the parent component. Does this not work?

```
<input
  type={props.type}
  name={props.name} 
  value={props.value} 
  onChange={(event) => props.handleChange(event)}                 
/>
```